# p styling not showing up. Typed out one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple html page.
I am using typed.js which is a Jquery plugin to make the text typed out.

The problem is none of the text which are in p tags are stylized when outputted.
Also the text in the p tags are printed out one by one.

I would like it to be typed out at one go.
Not sure how to fix these issues.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        center {
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10%;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
        p {
            /*font-family: Monaco, monospace; */
            font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            color:#00FF00;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Personal Website</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="">
    <center>
        <div id="typed-strings"> 
            <p>Some text </p>
            <p>This is some more text.</p>
            <p>No more text after this.</p>
        </div>
        <span id="typed"></span>
    </center>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="typed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#typed").typed({
                stringsElement: $('#typed-strings'),
                typeSpeed: 0,
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me you code is working check here the change is you not given style for ,#typed

http://jsfiddle.net/8CbL2/25/

```
   p,#typed {
            /*font-family: Monaco, monospace; */
            font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            color:#00FF00;
        }
```

Comment: After adding p,#typed, it is working. Thank you. I still need to figure out how to type out all the text at one go without any overwriting.

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/8CbL2/26/ or http://jsfiddle.net/8CbL2/27/

Answer (score 1):

This is because `typed.js` will type your text into another HTML element. In your code, you specify it to type into the `span` with `id=typed`. So add this selector to your CSS:

```
p, #typed {
    /*font-family: Monaco, monospace; */
    font-family: 'Lucida Console', monospace;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #00FF00;
}
```

And if you want to target the typing cursor as well, add `.typed-cursor` to your selector list as well.

Comment: I do not fully understand. do u mean something like this: .typed-cursor, #typed {....}   ?

Comment: yes, since `typed.js` draws the cursor with an HTML element of class "`typed-cursor`". If you want the original text to also be styled, then say `p, #typed, .typed-cursor { ... }`